# Growth of n multichoose k when n and k increase by the same number

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs, multisets

The multiset coefficient

$$\left (\binom{n}{k}  \right ) = \binom{n+k-1}{k}$$

denotes the number of multisets of cardinality k, with elements taken from a finite set of cardinality n. I'm interested in how this number grows when both n and k are increased by an integer x.

$$\left (\binom{n+x}{k+x}  \right ) = \binom{n+k+2x-1}{k+x}$$

I've done some plotting and it appears this number grows exponentially with x, but I haven't been able to prove this. How would I do it?

Comment: Would it not make sense if you simply replace $n$ by $n+x$ and $k$  by $k+x$?

Comment: You can prove that is grows like $4^x$ using Stirling's approximation. See [Wikipedia, binomial coefficients, both *n* and *k* large](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Both_n_and_k_large).

Comment: Actually, it should be $4^x/\sqrt{\pi x}$.

Answer (score 0):

The ratio between consecutive terms

$$\frac{\binom{n + k + 2x + 1}{k + x + 1}}{\binom{n + k + 2x - 1}{k + x}} = \frac{(n + k + 2x + 1)(n + k + 2x)}{(k + x + 1)(n + x)}$$

converges to $4$ as $x \to \infty$.